# Stream does not end

Tags: vb.net, stream, server-sent-events

I try to write a Client that consumes a Server-Sent-Event using this code:

```
Public Shared Function OpenSSEStream(ByVal url As String, ByVal _token As String, ByVal _identifier As String, ByVal _environment As String) As Stream
    Dim request = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(url))
    CType(request, HttpWebRequest).AllowReadStreamBuffering = False
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization:Bearer " + _token)
    request.Headers.Add("environment:" + _environment)
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("id", _identifier)
    Dim response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    SSEApplication.ReadStreamForever(stream)
    Return stream
End Function

Public Shared Sub ReadStreamForever(ByVal stream As Stream)
    Dim encoder = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim buffer = New Byte(2047) {}

    While True
        If stream.CanRead Then
            Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)
            If len > 0 Then
                Dim text = encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, len)
            End If
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

This works great so for, I can see the text from the server (in debug mode) in the text Variable. Unfortunately, if I run the code (not debugging) I get in Break Mode. I can see in Debug Mode that the text file is filled with about 2000 datasets and it looks like the stream does not end and runs into an endless loop or so? Can anyone help me here?

Comment: An endless loop, you say?  Gee, I can't see one of those in that code... unless I bother to read it.

Comment: As long as len > 0 I have text coming in and everything is ok. But even if len = 0 (means there is no text in the stream?) the While - Loop still gones on.

Comment: Use `While stream.CanRead` ... otherwise it goes on and on and on... Right now the condition `True` is `True` nothing will ever change that condition... I recommend reading [**While...End While Statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/while-end-while-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exit the loop, there's nothing right now that tells it to exit.

```
While True
    If stream.CanRead Then
        Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)
        If len > 0 Then
            Dim text = encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, len)
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    Else
        Exit While
    End If
End While
```

Also, a stream can receive the information only in pieces. You should concatenate the data.

```
Dim text As String = ""

While True
    If stream.CanRead Then
        Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)
        If len > 0 Then
            text &= encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, len)
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    Else
        Exit While
    End If
End While
```

This can all be refactor

```
Dim streamData As New StringBuilder

While stream.CanRead
    Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)

    If len > 0 Then
        ' There is the possibility that a Unicode character be split
        streamData.Append(encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, len))
    Else
         Exit While
    End If
End While
```

Comment: What is the point of having an `Else` statement if the `While` condition is met? You are adding more conditions that are not needed, the if check's can go away and the else statements... The fix should be forming a conditional statement that meets the `while` condition, not slapping `True` on it, bad practice IMHO... Also you could then add more than one condition to the `while` which then in return would provide better clarity overall.

Comment: Hi. Since the answer above is apparentely not good and I am totally in doubt about my own, could you create an answer with your solution this would help and would have a good learning effect as well.

Comment: It is working. I was just curious about his fancier solution. One additional question. Does the 2048 limit the input I can read? Since I do not know how much is comming can I just change it to e.g. 100000?

Comment: @ruedi you could. You can also create a big buffer, read 2048 at a time and fill up the buffer, then convert the buffer into a string.